# Django Session Authentication With CSRF Middleware logins successfully but returns 403 on next requests

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-authentication, django-sessions

I am using Django session auth with csrf middleware. And using angular for frontend. Front end makes a login request and my backend login logs in the user & csrf token is set in cookie, and passed in the further requests.

I am able to login and can see the cookie being passed on next requests, but I am getting 403 with `Authentication credentials were not provided`.

Here are my `setttings.py` && `views.py`.

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'reversion.middleware.RevisionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    # 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
    ),
}

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)
```

Here is my `view.py`

```
class LoginView(APIView):
    serializer_class = CustomUserSerialzer

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        data = request.data
        email = data.get('email', None)
        password = data.get('password', None)
        try:
            user = authenticate(request, username=email, password=password)
            if user is not None:
                login(request, user)
                return Response(self.serializer_class(user).data)
            raise Exception('Account has no access')
        except Exception as e:
            return Response({
                'status': 'Unauthorized',
                'message': str(e)
            }, status=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)
```

I cannot think of any reason why it would fail on requests after successful login though csrf token passed. I am sure I am missing something in my settings. Can someone suggest what my mistake is?

Answer (score 0):

Figured. I didn't notice I commented out `'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware'`.